# Prove that $\text{lim}_{\Delta t} \rightarrow 0$ of the transition PDF of a std Weiner process is 0

Tags: limits, probability-distributions, brownian-motion, markov-process

The transition probability density function of the standard Wiener process is:
$$ f(x_2,t_2|x_1,t_1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi (t_2-t_1)}}e^{-\frac{(x_2-x_1)^2}{2(t_2-t_1)^2}} $$

I know that if Markov process is continuous, then its transition probability density function satisfies, $\forall \epsilon > 0$ and uniformly in $x_1$, $t$, and $\Delta t$
$$ \text{lim}_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\Delta t} \int_{|x_2-x_1|>\epsilon} f(x_2, t+\Delta t|x_1, t) dx_2 = 0 $$

I would like to prove it for the standard Wiener process above. If anyone has an idea that would be very appreciated

Comment: I am not familiar with this property but considering the integral as a probability might be useful. More precisely, $f(x_2,t+\Delta t \ | \ x_1,t)$ is the density function of a normal distributed random variable with mean $x_1$ and variance $\Delta t$. As you might know, integrating the density is the same as computing probabilities over the integration region.

Comment: I see. I don't get how to use this information to solve the limit though. Intuitively I think that the limit makes sense, but mathematically I don't know how to prove it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that 
$$f(x_2,t+\Delta t \ | \ x_1,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \Delta t}} \exp\left\{\frac{-1}{2}\frac{(x_2-x_1)^2}{\Delta t}\right\},$$
Hence we can write (let $u = x_2-x_1$)
\begin{align}
&\int_{|x_2-x_1|>\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \Delta t}} \exp\left\{\frac{-1}{2}\frac{(x_2-x_1)^2}{\Delta t}\right\}dx_2 \\
&= \int_{|u|>\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \Delta t}} \exp\left\{\frac{-u^2}{2\Delta t}\right\}du \\
&= 2 \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \Delta t}} \exp\left\{\frac{-u^2}{2\Delta t}\right\}du. \\
\end{align}
Let $u/\sqrt{\Delta t} = w \Rightarrow du = dw \sqrt{\Delta }$ and hence the above integral reduces to
\begin{align}
&2 \int_{\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\Delta t}}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left\{\frac{-w^2}{2}\right\}dw.  \\
&= 2\left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\Delta t}}\right)\right),
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf. Hence,
\begin{align} &\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta t} \int_{|x_2-x_1|>\epsilon} f(x_2,t+\Delta t \ | \ x_1,t)dx_2 \\
&= \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{2}{\Delta t} \left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\Delta t}}\right)\right) \quad (*)
\end{align}
You can prove that $(*)$ is indeed equal to zero. One possibility is to use l'Hopital's rule. Another possibility is an application of Markov's inequality.

Comment: Markov's inequality sounds like a great idea. Thank you